# Java Data Structure for string matching

Tags: java, data-structures, matching

I have a long list of arbitrary strings and I'd like to determine if my given string "ABADCAFE" starts with any of the strings in my list. Is there a library class somewhere that can do this for me reasonably efficiently ?

(I suppose it's much like the state machine built by regex, but I don't think composing a regex is the way to go here - my list is too long)

Comment: Not sure if this will actually work, so I won't post it as an answer:

Perhaps build a Tree where the nodes are the letters in the string. A parent may only have one child. A parent's child is its next letter, and a leaf has a child of null. Iterate over the Tree to search for possible words.

Comment: foreach instruction would be too inefficient?

Comment: I suppose I should've added that the iteration is repeated; i.e. the long list is used multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably a Patricia Tree or Radix Tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Apache Commons Collections and Google Collections Library appear to have the same implementation: http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is some magic algorithm here that would give you super efficiency; after all, the algorithm has to take a look at each string. Building a finite state machine or a radix tree, or using the foreach -- they're all linear in the number of strings and for this application just quite the same.